# How dynamically define and create custom "through" model with specific fields and structure for all custom manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model with a lot of m2m fields:

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    useful_data = models.TextField(null=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    useful_data = models.TextField(null=True)

class Entity(models.Model):
    field1 = CustomManyToManyField('entities.Model1')
    field2 = CustomManyToManyField('entities.Model2')
    field3 = CustomManyToManyField('entities.Model2')
    ...
```

I want a override "through" model auto creation logic to add some additional fields to store additional meta information about relation.
So for example, for `field1` field intermediary model will be created with fields:

```
class CustomThroughModel(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey('entities.Organization')
    model1 = models.ForeignKey('entities.Model1')

    # And additional meta information
    data_source = models.CharField()

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I don't want to copy paste similar models for every manytomanyfields. 
I want to specify only `CustomManyToManyField` without explicitly specifying every "through" (It should be handled dynamically). 
How can I override ManyToManyField to add this logic?

Comment: Make an abstract base model and just add the one foreign key for each concrete through  model.

Comment: I suppose you're simplifying, but somehow these models seem flawed. Why have Model1, Model2, etc? They're the same.